# Converting monthly data into daywise table in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this in R:-

```
NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT   MONTH    YEAR
127                 9        2017
125                 10       2017
120                 11       2017
130                 12       2017
110                 1        2018
125                 2        2018
```

I need to convert MONTH data to day wise data and my data frame should look like this:-

```
    NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT   MONTH     YEAR  DAY
    127                 9        2017   1
    127                 9        2017   2
    127                 9        2017   3
    127                 9        2017   4
    .
    .

    .
    127                 9        2017   30
    125                 10       2017    1
    125                 10       2017    2
```

and so on for every month.
I tried finding a similar question but it didn't work.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT   MONTH    YEAR
127                 9        2017
125                 10       2017
120                 11       2017
130                 12       2017
110                 1        2018
125                 2        2018", h = T)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Supriya, and congratulations on your first question.

I notice someone has downvoted your question already without providing feedback, which is a bit mean.  You might want to edit your question and fill in some detail about what you have researched so far.   You may find this guide helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `tidyverse` and `lubridate` -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  uncount(
    weights = days_in_month(make_date(YEAR, MONTH)),
    .id = "Day"
  )
```

Comment: emp_data <- emp_data%>%uncount(weights = days_in_month(as.Date(str_c(Year,"-",Month,"-",1))),.id="Day")

Comment: No problem. Consider up-voting or marking this as correct using the tick mark at top left of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another `lubdridate` / `tidyverse` way :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(DAY = map2(
    YEAR, MONTH, ~seq(days_in_month(as.Date(str_c(.x,"-",.y,"-",1)))))) %>%
  unnest
#    NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT MONTH YEAR day
# 1               127     9 2017   1
# 2               127     9 2017   2
# 3               127     9 2017   3
# 4               127     9 2017   4
# ...
```

Comment: It gave below result:    NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT Month Year day
1            127.24     9 2017   1
2            127.24     9 2017   2
3            127.24     9 2017   3
4            127.24     9 2017   4
5            127.24     9 2017   5
6            127.24     9 2017   6
7            127.24     9 2017   7
8            127.24     9 2017   8
9            127.06    10 2017   1
10           127.06    10 2017   2
It was going till Day 8 only . I guess it is taking the total months:8 and giving sequence till that.

Comment: This worked for me:-   emp_data <- emp_data%>%uncount(weights = days_in_month(as.Date(str_c(Year,"-",Month,"-",1))),.id="Day").... Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
     mydata<-data.frame(NO_Empl=c(127,125,124),Month=c(9,8,7),Year=c(2017,2018,2017))
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
as.tibble(mydata) %>% 
  mutate(Date=make_date(Year,Month)) %>% 
  select(-Month,-Year) %>% 
  mutate(Day=wday(Date),Day_date=month(Date))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  NO_Empl Date         Day Day_date
    <dbl> <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     127 2017-09-01     6        9
2     125 2018-08-01     4        8
3     124 2017-07-01     7        7
```

Answer (score 0):

0 dependency, 2x faster base R solution:

```
read.table(text="NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT   MONTH    YEAR
    127                 9        2017
    125                 10       2017
    120                 11       2017
    130                 12       2017
    110                 1        2018
    125                 2        2018", header=TRUE) -> xdf

do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(1:nrow(xdf), function(idx) {
    time <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(sprintf("%s-%02s-01", xdf$YEAR[idx], xdf$MONTH[idx])))
    time$mday[] <- time$sec[] <- time$min <- time$hour <- 0
    time$mon <- time$mon + 1
    data.frame(
      YEAR = xdf$YEAR[idx],
      MONTH = xdf$MONTH[idx],
      DAY = seq(1:as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(time))$mday),
      NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT = xdf$NO_OF_EMPLOYMENT[idx]
    )  
  })
)
```